# How to make FakeItEasy capture full argument state?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fakeiteasy

I have a piece of code like this (simplified):

```
await realApiClient.DoSomething(entity);
entity.Email = newEmail;
await realApiClient.DoSomethingElse(entity);
```

In my test I have created a fake and want to check that both `DoSomething` and `DoSomethingElse` were called. So I do it like this:

```
A.CallTo(() => fakeApiClient.DoSomething(A<Entity>
        .That.Matches(p => p.Email == "p123@okdomain.com"
    )))
    .MustHaveHappenedOnceExactly();

A.CallTo(() => fakeApiClient.DoSomethingElse(A<Entity>
        .That.Matches(p => p.Email != "p123@okdomain.com"
    )))
    .MustHaveHappenedOnceExactly();
```

The problem - the test for `DoSomething` fails because FakeItEasy seems to not capture the full state of the method call arguments. When I check the email in `DoSomething` call, FakeItEasy is checking against the value that was updated in `entity.Email = newEmail;` and not the original value before the update.

As soon as I comment out `entity.Email = newEmail;` then `DoSomething` test succeeds. But then, of course, `DoSomethingElse` rightfully fails because it expected the email to be changed.

What is the proper way to access the argument state as it actually was at the time when `DoSomething` was called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FakeItEasy doesn't (and likely never will) store a snapshot of an object's state, for reasons discussed mostly in the accepted answer to [MustHaveHappened fails when called twice on the same object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12846484/1199) and also in [Verifying multiple method calls with reference parameters](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/issues/306).

There are hints there about manually capturing important state to preserve it between calls.

In your simple example, though, one option might be to [invoke a custom method](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/invoking-custom-code/) in your "arrange" phase, having it capture the important parts of the argument. Something like

```cs
var capturedEmails = new List<String>();
A.CallTo(() => fakeApiClient.DoSomething(A<Entity>._))
    .Invokes((Entity e) => capturedEmails.Add(e.Email));
…
await realApiClient.DoSomething(entity);
entity.Email = newEmail;
await realApiClient.DoSomethingElse(entity);
…
capturedEmails.Should().ContainExactly("p123@okdomain.com");
```

(not run nor even compiled but you get the gist)